# Understanding NSURL, in the context of retrieving a persistent store document

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

Learning to use coreData. Currently looking at Stanford's CS193P Lecture 14, which is very helpful. I have successfully set up a working app with core data persistence, using a ManagedDocument.

This code below is run every time the app starts.  My confusion is: how do we know that the url for the document is correct? How does it know that "lastObject" will always be the URL for the saved document?

```
if (!myManagedDocument) {        
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"theDatabase"];
    myManagedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
}
```

This code below will open the document, or create/save it if it has not already been saved previously.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[myManagedDocument.fileURL path]]) {
        [myManagedDocument saveToURL:myManagedDocument.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL sucess) {
            [self getInfoFromDatabase];
        }];
    } else if (myManagedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [myManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL sucess) {
            [self getInfoFromDatabase];
        }];
    } else if (myManagedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        [self getInfoFromDatabase];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the `directory` and `domainMask` argument, `URLsForDirectory` can return
an array of several URLs. For example, on OS X,

```
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSAllDomainsMask];
```

returns

```
(
file://localhost/Users/<user>/Library/Application%20Support/,
file://localhost/Library/Application%20Support/,
file://localhost/Network/Library/Application%20Support/
)
```

But in your case, on iOS,

```
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
```

returns an array of *exactly one* URL, which is the document directory inside the
application sandbox. On the simulator, this would look like

```
(
file://localhost/Users/<user>/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE/Documents/
)
```

So it does not matter if you take the first or last object of that array.
The code just assumes that the managed document is saved in *the* document directory
of the application sandbox.